# Trying to Control a DGH D8500 modbus via python

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus, minimalmodbus

i have this Two channel Analog Output modbus RTU protocol USB Interface named, DGH D8500. I need to control the voltage of the channels dynamically and automated through python. I connected it i tried it with its own program, but I'm failing to communicate with it using python, i tried using pymodbus and minimalmodbus but i don't seem to receive any type of response:

baudrate=9600, parity = none, bytesize = 8, stopbyte 1

- [Modbus Quickstart Manual](https://www.dghcorp.com/datasheets/D8000_USB_QuickStart_Guide.pdf)
- [Modbus User Manal](https://www.dghcorp.com/manuals/D8000_USB_UsersManual.pdf)

Pymodbus code

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient
import serial
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

instrument = ModbusSerialClient(method='rtu', port='COM3', baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=1, bytesize=8)
print instrument.connect()
print instrument

value = instrument.read_holding_registers(40113, unit=1)
print value
```

Pymodbus error

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Current transaction state - IDLE
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:SEND: 0x1 0x3 0x9c 0xb1 0x0 0x1 0xfa 0x7d
DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:New Transaction state 'SENDING'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
True
ModbusSerialClient(rtu baud[9600])
Exception Response(131, 3, IllegalAddress)
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:RECV: 0x1 0x83 0x2 0xc0 0xf1
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Getting Frame - 0x83 0x2
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Response[131]
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame advanced, resetting header!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Adding transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Getting transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Minimalmodbus Code

```
import minimalmodbus

instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM3', 1, mode='rtu', debug=True)
instrument.serial.baudrate = 9600
print instrument

value = instrument.read_register(registeraddress=40113, number_of_decimals=3, functioncode=3, signed=False)
print value
```

Minimalmodbus error

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 192.5728.105)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Create serial port COM3
minimalmodbus.Instrument<id=0x39aee88, address=1, mode=rtu, close_port_after_each_call=False, precalculate_read_size=True, clear_buffers_before_each_transaction=True, handle_local_echo=False, debug=True, serial=Serial<id=0x3ae1518, open=True>(port='COM3', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=0.05, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)>
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 7 bytes back): '\x01\x03\x9c\xb1\x00\x01\xfa}' (01 03 9C B1 00 01 FA 7D)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM3
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 1574707870601.00 ms, minimum silent period: 4.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '' () (0 bytes), roundtrip time: 63.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 50.0 ms.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2060, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2054, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1405, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1412, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:/Users/naxso/PycharmProjects/modbus_virt/minimal_modbus.py", line 8, in <module>
    value = instrument.read_register(registeraddress=40113, number_of_decimals=3, functioncode=3, signed=False)
  File "C:\Users\naxso\PycharmProjects\modbus_virt\venv\lib\site-packages\minimalmodbus.py", line 447, in read_register
    payloadformat=_PAYLOADFORMAT_REGISTER,
  File "C:\Users\naxso\PycharmProjects\modbus_virt\venv\lib\site-packages\minimalmodbus.py", line 1170, in _generic_command
    payload_from_slave = self._perform_command(functioncode, payload_to_slave)
  File "C:\Users\naxso\PycharmProjects\modbus_virt\venv\lib\site-packages\minimalmodbus.py", line 1240, in _perform_command
    response = self._communicate(request, number_of_bytes_to_read)
  File "C:\Users\naxso\PycharmProjects\modbus_virt\venv\lib\site-packages\minimalmodbus.py", line 1406, in _communicate
    raise NoResponseError("No communication with the instrument (no answer)")
minimalmodbus.NoResponseError: No communication with the instrument (no answer)
```

I really don't understand quite well its my firs time working with this and I'm following the instructions to the steps but maybe its only a little error of me because of my little knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple solution for a very common problem.

If you look at the pymodbus log, you'll see this line:

```
Exception Response(131, 3, IllegalAddress)
```

That means the register you are trying to read does not exist.

This happens because the way you refer to Modbus register addresses is a bit confusing. Most devices use address 40xxx for holding registers, but when you actually read those registers you need to refer to them subtracting 40000. So if you want to read register 40113 you should do:

```
value = instrument.read_holding_registers(113, unit=1)
```

If you want to print the value stored in the register be aware that you have to call it explicitly:

```
print value.registers[0]
```

**EDIT**: As discussed below sometimes the offset is 40001 instead of 40000. So if you want to read register 40114 you need to query 40114-40001=113.

Comment: Ok, i manage to get a type of response the thing is that trough its software i set up the Chanel 2 to 5 volts, and reading register 40114 witch its "Present Output CH2" i get 0, but if i read 40113 witch its the same but for CH1 i get, 32767. No number near the voltage i set up, and its reading something on the channel where the voltage its 0.

Comment: Hello, I forgot to mention something important. Sometimes the offset is 40001 instead of 40000. So if you want to read register 40114 you need to query 40114-40001=113. With that in mind I think your readings  make full sense. Apologies if I was misleading. I will update my answer tomorrow

Comment: To make sure your offset is correct you should query registers 40001 (0) and 40002 (1) to check you see the right settings: slave address, baud rate and parity

Comment: I figured the offset already. All registers where minus one. In terms of what i received **32767**, i researched how to convert it t volts ```value=( response value * Vref ) / Max response value``` and got the correct voltage. The only problem that im having right know is that i'm trying to write in the set point register 49 for channel 2, and i'm getting no response in the channel neither the multi meter.

Comment: You might need to write a 2 onto register 40241 (control) before writing to 40049, if I understood the manual on a very quick reading

Comment: Yeah, i saw it, i'm trying ```instrument.write_register(address=control_register(40241 - 40001), value=2)```

But the response its:

```DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Transaction failed. (Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received))```

Comment: update: Tried using, ```instrument.write_register(address=control_register(40241 - 40001), value=2, unit=1)```, and it passed. Tried writing and then ```DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame advanced, resetting header!!``` and transaction complete and all but voltage its not changing or sometimes its sends ```DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Incomplete message received, Expected 8 bytes Recieved 7 bytes !!!!```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, maybe it's better if you post a new question with the complete logs.